# After sox merge get resulting files shorter than source

Tags: sox

Im trying to Merge two files with the same length (ex. 2:16) with

```
sox -M left.ogg right.ogg mixed.ogg remix 1 2
```

But as a result I'm getting file shorter 1-10 seconds (ex. 2:08)

Also this resulted file I can't open with Audacity but chrome plays it fine.

Comment: Can you provide the audio files? Since you can listen to the final audio, can you tell where the cut is done? Which part is missing?

Comment: As an example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4294576/example/left.ogg https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4294576/example/right.ogg https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4294576/example/mixed.ogg

Comment: When I'm doing that in console result is fine, but I need to run this by asterisk AGI script. So I'm getting that result withoul last some seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do this in a single command, however:

1. If you run`sox -M left.ogg right.ogg mixed_stereo.ogg` you obtain a two channel file of the right length
2. If you then want to reduce the file into mono, you can run `sox mixed_stereo.ogg mixed_mono.ogg remix 1,2`

Comment: No didn't helped. Still cuts ending even without remix.

Comment: It works for me. Final mixed file is 29.96 sec long.

Comment: strange what is yours version of sox, I have v14.2.0

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, SoX v14.4.1

Comment: strange when I'm running it in console it works as you say, but I need to run it by asterisk AGI script with exec => System(...) and after that getting that striped result.